# Xamarin Android WebView EME API

Tags: xamarin.android, android-webview, eme

Does Xamarin Android WebView have access to the EME API?
If not can it be activated?
If it can't be activated, is there anything similar to WebView that has access to the EME API?

Comment: Refer to:https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/eme#getting_a_key_from_a_license_server

Comment: EME API is more of HTML spec. so it must be supported by webview (chrome) implementation. I don't think so there will be an restriction on Xamarin.